# Joomla 3 - Generate URL based on article alias without creating menu item

Tags: joomla, routes, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions, sef

**Description:**
I have almost 4,000 articles and now i want the SEF URLs for them all based on alias of each article is it possible if i can achieve this without creating menu items? 
i.e (www.websitename.com/article-alis)

**Problem:**
I know i can achieve this if i create menu items for them all but i don't want to create 4,000 menu items and want some quick and easy way but based on article alias so i can change it whenever i want.

Thanks, Aamir

Comment: I know i can do this using category blog layout, but then i get category name in the URL and also article id as well, 
(i.e my-cat-name/6-articlealias.html), so 6 is article if which i don't want and also dont want category name in the URL

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE**

If you want make that, you must do rename `htaccess.txt` (for activate SEO Control) and modify your `.htaccess` (on main folder site) and peraps create your propers rules.

**First :** Have you renmae the `htaccess.txt` file (on main folder site) to `.htaccess`?

is here where contain all rules for rewriting!

> Example: RewriteRule ^folder1.*$ http://example.com/folder2/ [R=301,L]

On this example, all article start on folder name `folde1`is rewrite by `folder2`

You can see more : https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204643270/using-htaccess-rewrite-rules

or for Joomla 3 rewriting : https://docs.joomla.org/Enabling_Search_Engine_Friendly_%28SEF%29_URLs

Comment: Thank you for the reply but i have done it already, if you can see my last comment then you will see its SEF URL and all settings on admin already active, what i want is when i create blog category layout and click on blog article titles to link those articles then i get article id and category name in the URL which i dont want and only want something like this www.MySite.com/MyArticleAlias

Comment: Ok what is your e commerce component?

Comment: i am not using ecommerce, its default joomla, for example i created 100 articles in a category and want the SEF URLs without creating menu items but URLs must have to be: websitename.com/articleAlias.
Currently i know if i create category blog layout then it allows me auto create URLs based on article Alias but its also showing article id and category name with it which i dont want to show

Comment: Unfortunately i tried all that already and no luck, i have the .htaccess on my root and i have already SEF URLs, but not like i want.
i.e when i create an article in joomla i have to create menu item for it to create SEF URL and the url is based on menu item:
mywebsite.com/MenuItemAlias

I want to know if there is a way i can get SEF URLs based on article alias without creating menu items (as i have over 4k Articles and dont want to create all menu items) and i can get URL like this without creating all menu items:
websitename.com/ArticleAlias